# Convert "only/except" clauses to "rules" clause in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

#### Problem Summary:

My goal is to add a `rules` clause to configure a Gitlab CI job to run if an environment variable is set, or if manual action is performed. Unfortunately, the step currently makes use of `only` and `except` clauses so I'll have to also convert them into `rules` syntax, which I've not fully grasped yet.

#### Current Job Definition:

```yaml
deploy:
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    refs:
      - /flux-.*$/  
      - master
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
```

#### Required Changes:

I'll be replacing

```yaml
when: manual
```

with

```yaml
rules:
  - if: '$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME'
  - when: manual
```

Now I'd like to learn how to translate the `only/except` clauses. I think it'll be completely based on predefined environment variable tests, though I'm unsure which variables are of interest for this translation.

Many thanks for any suggestions or pointers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you pointed out using [predefined environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) is the way to go with `rules`. Many of them can be used to achieve the same thing, it really depends on your needs (For example: `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` vs `$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG` vs `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`).

> My goal is to add a rules clause to configure a Gitlab CI job to run if an environment variable is set, or if manual action is performed.

Just to be sure to understand what you mean by that:

- If `$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME` then always run the deploy job, otherwise if the branch is *not* `master` and doesn't match `/flux-.*$/`, then allow the `deploy` job to be triggered manually.

Is that correct?

If yes, one implementation would look like this below. (You can also use `||` operators to merge the 2 first rules if you want)

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /flux-.*$/'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME'
    - when: manual
```

Keep in mind that `rules` are evaluated in order. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, you understood me correctly. Thank you.
The first issue was that using `CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME` did not work for testing if an environment is already setup for a certain feature branch. I'm starting to doubt there's a way to test for that through predefined env variables.
The second issue is the `only` clause which I couldn't translate with `rules`. I tried testing if `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != ""` (not with that syntax ofc) but that didn't do it. An extra detached job is created each time, still.